My React Native Expo app crashes when I render a MapView
I'm making an app about a simple social media where you can share your location while you are in a walk, and I'm using MapView component of react-native-maps. When I use Expo Go, everything is okey, but when I make the build, the apk crashes when I go those components which use a MapView on them. I thought the reason was location permissions, but that's not true since I did testing with a component that doesn't use any location of the device, just hardcoding coordinates on the MapView props, but I don't know the reason yet...
I don't have any API key of Google Maps, but I don't know why that could be a problem since in Expo Go using my device everything is okey... I'm stuck.
I'll give you the sample of code that I used in the component where I publish a new location:
const [location, setLocation] = useState({
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
    })
const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Permission denied')
        return
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})

    const currentLocation = {
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude
    }
    setLocation(currentLocation)
}
const addNewLocation = () => {
    const newLocation = {
        location: {
            latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude
        },
        title: title,
        description: description,
        author: authData._id,
    }
    axios.post(`${URL}/addNewPublication`, newLocation)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.data)
        })
}
useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentLocation()
}, [])

And then, inside the return between other elements:
<MapView 
   style={{
       width: '100%',
       height: '40%',
   }}
   region={{
       latitude: location.latitude,
       longitude: location.longitude,
       latitudeDelta: 0.09,
       longitudeDelta: 0.04
   }}
   scrollEnabled={false}
   zoomEnabled={false}
   >
     <Marker 
         coordinate={{
             latitude: location.latitude,
             longitude: location.longitude,
             latitudeDelta: 0.09,
             longitudeDelta: 0.04
         }}
     />
</MapView>


What I expect is the app doesn't crash when it displays a MapView, and I don't know the reason why right now, if could be a prop bad defined, not using an API key for Google Maps...
Thank you and sorry for my low english level
